# Как записать в переменную канал или роль? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Идея:**

> Я хочу сделать 1 команду что бы она закрывала 3-ом(существующим) разным ролям право на общение в 3-ох разных каналах(текстовых, существующих).

Вот к примеру тут я создаю канал и записываю его в переменную, а потом меняю права:

```
channel = await integration.guild.create_voice_channel(f"{integration.user.name}'s voice ", category=category)
await channel.set_permissions(integration.user, overwrite=overwrite)
```

А как записать в переменную существующий канал или роль что бы потом у него изменять права и тд?

**Подскажите как это сделать?**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: тогда немного изменю свой вопрос: как правильно указывать в скрипте какой канал надо изменить?
вот к примеру я тут создал канал в переменную:
```py
channel = await integration.guild.create_voice_channel(f"{integration.user.name}'s voice ", category=category)
 await channel.set_permissions(integration.user, overwrite=overwrite)
```

__А как записать канал или роль в переменную не создавая новый канал?__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь помогают решить проблему, а не пишет за Вас код.
Вы не приложили к вопросу никаких попыток написать собственную команду, поэтому просто дам наводку, где можно найти информацию.

Официальная документация *discord py* как раз для этого и создана:

**Изменение прав роли** — https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.edit

**Сами права** — https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions

В одну команду добавляете три действия, то есть изменение трём указанным ролям необходимые права и всё.

**Для изменение прав на конкретном канале** — https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions

(можно указать роль или конкретного человека в параметрах)

Comment: тогда немного изменю свой вопрос: как правильно указывать в скрипте какой канал надо изменить?
очевидно что не через айди

Comment: И да прошу прощения за то что не предоставил скрипт.

Comment: Вот к примеру тут я записываю канал в переменную и так изменяю но как сделать так что бы уже существующий канал изменить?

channel = await integration.guild.create_voice_channel(f"{integration.user.name}'s voice ", category=category)
await channel.set_permissions(integration.user, overwrite=overwrite)